# Как настроить маршрутизацию в Angular -route + Django?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, http

Добрый день! Делаю одностраничное приложение на Django + Angular с использованием Rest-framework.
На этапе настройки маршрутизации с помощью angular-route возникла следующая проблема: при открытии в браузере экранируется пустая страница, при этом в консоли разработчика не переставая вылетают ошибки, а на вкладке постоянно крутится иконка загрузки. Маршрутизация настроена по примеру из элементарных туториалов:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('uniApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller : 'mainCtrl',
      templateUrl : '../views/main.html'
    })
    .when('/\d', {
      controller : 'detailCtrl',
      templateUrl : '../views/detail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v0/cases/').success(function(data){
    $scope.cases = data;
  });
});
app.controller('detailCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="uniApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>UNI DIGIT</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Постарался переписать весь код в точности, как в примерах из туториалов, но проблема не изчезла.
Возможно, дело в Django, но ведь он не имеет отношения к фронтэнду..

Comment: в роутинге Django прописан этот `index.html`?

Comment: Да, прописан. Джанго на все запросы отдаёт только его

Comment: что значит на все запросы? Django должен отдавать этот темплейт один раз  и далее Angular строит свой роутинг оттуда, обращаясь к серверному API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в urls.py, когда ангуляр делал запрос по templateUrl : '../views/main.html' Джанго бесконечно отдавал index.html, так как в урл Джанго было указано url(r'^', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index').
Проблему удалось решить путём переноса шаблонов в папку media и указания на первом месте урл-паттернах static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT).
Понимаю, что хранение шаблонов в медиа - не самое лучшее решение, но пока я нашёл только такое

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl - это url, не путь.
В urls.py нужно было прописать или функции которые отвечают за /views/main.html и /views/detail.html

или используем отдчау html без views.py, то в urls.py будет следующее

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r"^views/main\.html$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),
    url(r"^views/detail\.html$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='detail.html')),]
```

В самих шаблонах необходимо отключать обработку тегов {{ }} для angular.

```
{%load verbatim%}

<p>{%verbatim%}
<p>this where your angular tags "{{}}" resides
<p>{%endverbatim%}
```

Или переопределять шаблонный тег для angular.